# Ansible playbook chain error handling

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that looks like the following

```
-name: deploy web
  -hosts:
    -tag_Name_my_web_server
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: True
  sudo_user: app
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
    - role: "deploy/web"

-name: deploy job
  -hosts:
    -tag_Name_my_job_server
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: True
  sudo_user: app
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
    - role: "deploy/job"
```

So basically I am deploying to 2 groups of servers (web and job). Sometimes the deploy to web fails, in which case I would like my playbook to abort and **not continue** to deploy the job server.

I am unaware of any Ansible configs that will abort the whole playbook if the first step fails.

I have looked into `max_fail_percentage` but that seems to only be for a group of hosts, so even if deploy web fails it will continue to deploy job.

I have a feeling what I want to do is not possible and I would have to break these up into separate calls to `ansible-playbook`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you desire is actually the default. A failure of a task in the web role would stop execution, aborting any subsequent tasks.

I notice some curious patterns in your sample code, however. At least two things stand out:

- The `hosts` keyword is not a list and should not be prefixed with a dash. This is a syntax error.
- Roles should not contain a `/` character. A more suitable approach would be a variable to dictate the type to deploy.

A fixed version of the code looks like this:

```
- name: deploy web
  hosts: tag_Name_my_web_server
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: True
  sudo_user: app
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
  - { role: deploy, deploy_type: web }

- name: deploy job
  hosts: tag_Name_my_job_server
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: True
  sudo_user: app
  gather_facts: True
  roles:
  - { role: deploy, deploy_type: job }
```

Then in your `deploy` role you can use the `deploy_type` variable in a condition to determine which tasks to execute/files to include. For better readability I'd lean towards include a file based on the type.